# Mantis Bug tracker severity options customization

Tags: php, customization, mantis

When we `Report Issue` in Mantis, there comes `Severity` option, where I want to add one custom field, which should display in that drop down.

Any idea which files needs to change this for or can we manage it from Database?

Any body has done this kind of customization into Mantis? I'm using Mantis 1.1.6 version, but other version updates will also do for me.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you  have the access to Mantis' source code to find out for yourself regarding which file(s) to change? I'm posting a link here which may give you a start. http://www.mantisbt.org/manual/manual.customizing.mantis.php. But, I feel this is something you have to explore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the severity is a MantisBT enumeration, the applicable documentation is [Customizing MantisBT -> Enumerations](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html#ADMIN.CUSTOMIZE.ENUMS).